# Securing you're app's ClientId and SecretKey in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, service-principal

What's the guidance for protecting: `ClientId` and `SecretKey` to avoid service identity impersonation?

These are used for `ServicePrincipal` authentication in Azure Active Directory using `OAuth`.

Currently, we're using config settings in our stateless-service.

Online recommendations suggest storing sensitive data in `KeyVault` however, in order to retrieve it the service needs to prove it's identity thus which requires the `ClientId` and `SecretKey`.

I am considering [encrypted configuration files](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/06/11/encrypting-the-web-config-file.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that at some point you need to store a secret inside your web server. You can add layers of obfuscation along the way by encrypting your config files or putting your secrets in Key Vault but at some point that server needs to obtain a plain text password to the resources it is accessing.

It very much depends on what the risk is that you are wanting to mitigate.

If you are looking to protect against an Azure Web App being compromised, it really doesn't matter what you do, your secrets are out.

If you want to keep your secrets safe from all but the security teams in your department, then key vault can provide a solution to that.

If you want to be able to deploy your entire codebase from Github, complete with encrypted Web.Config file, then that will solve that.

Understand the risks you are protecting against and work backwards from there.

The recommended approach from Azure is to simply store secure data as an App Setting, and to reference that environment variable from your application.

Its simple, it works and you don't need to store your secrets publically.

The majority of my scripts keep secrets in Keyvault, and the deployment script reads them from there and writes them into App Settings at deployment time.

Comment: How do you handle running the application locally during development?

Comment: Visual Studio / DNX has SecretManager which will present secrets stored in the user profile (in a json file) when the application is configured for development mode emulating how those secrets will be presented to Azure Web Apps.